# Initializer destroying information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a variable bill that I send to a hash:

```
bill = Hash
 'number' -> 2017
 'bill_type' -> h
 'sponsor_id' -> 400004
 and 23 more keys
```

this is passed to an initializer:

Bill.new(bill) and the result is an object with no data:

```
# and Bill.new(bill).to_json = {}
```

```
module GovKit
  module OpenCongress
    class Bill < OpenCongressObject
      attr_accessor :bill_type, :id, :introduced, :last_speech, :last_vote_date, :last_vote_roll, :last_vote_where, :last_action, :number, :plain_language_summary, :session, :sponsor, :co_sponsors, :title_full_common, :status, :most_recent_actions, :bill_titles, :recent_blogs, :recent_news, :ident

      def initialize(params)
        params.each do |key, value|
          instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) if Bill.instance_methods.include? key
        end      
      end
...
```

I am able to watch inside the initialize function, and the keys are defined, but the initializer consistently produces a consistently empty object. I am using rails 3.0.7, rubygems 1.6.2 and ruby "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]".

Comment: the gem author added this, note he is using ree (1.8.7): Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7) 
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > 
GovKit::OpenCongress::Bill.most_blogged_bills_this_week 
 => [#<GovKit::OpenCongress::Bill:0x1051fb728 
@last_vote_date=1306454160, @recent_news=[], @id=70461, 
@last_speech=nil, @recent_blogs=[], @co_sponsors=[],  so it is working for him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The gem author assumed that JSON.parse produced symbols to act as keys. Now the json gem produces strings as keys. Adding the to_sym below makes it work.

```
instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) if Bill.instance_methods.include? key.to_sym
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding attr_accessible for those fields.  Perhaps ruby/rails is smart enough to protect you from your own mass assignment.

Comment: that was my first thought, but it is not causing the problem here.